# Employees randomly drown themselves in nearby lake

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon

I'm playing RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe and I already observed it twice that a mechanic drowned in the lake. It happened in two different parks, in both cases there was a path and a rollercoaster station along the coast. I couldn't tell where exactly the mechanics drowned since I only got alerted by a red notification *"mechanic # has drowned!"* when they already were gone.

How and why does that happen?

Comment: No idea why... but maybe you could put a fence around the body of water to prevent them from walking in.

Comment: Maybe you could focus on improving working conditions... :-)

Comment: When the 'Mechanic # has drowned!' message appears, does the arrows button not appear alongside the message (the one that centres the view on where the event occurred)?

Answer (score 6):

It's to do with the terrible tracking of the AI. If a path is near a body of water, and a ride is also nearby, this can lead to them taking a "shortcut" through the nearest body of water.

This can also occur if a large section of path is deleted. They try to track back to the nearest section of path, but that doesn't always work out...

Comment: Really? In all my time playing RCT, I've never witnessed this and I'm pretty sure I've built my park in a similar manner at least once.  Never the less, I can believe this tragedy.

Comment: I used to build rides over/on the water, forcing the staff to take the paths that go over the water, this prevents them taking the "shortcut". I came to this same conclusion after a while and only seem to happen to mechanics and entertainers.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly.. They are taking a shortcut from/to the station off-path? And if it happens that there is water, they drown? I never observed that (except some handyman walking on grass, even when they were disallowed to mow it).